# Displaying json data using angularJS in html page

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-controller

I am trying to display data which is in json file in table using angularJS, but I get blank page as an output. The code is below. I have separate json file and separate js file in which I have defined angular controller. When I ran the application I got a blank page as an output.

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="angularTable">
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div role="main" class="container theme-showcase">
    <div class="" style="margin-top:90px">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h2 id="tables">Searching,Sorting and Pagination in angularJS.</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="bs-component" ng-controller="listdata">
                <table class="table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Hobby</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
                            <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{user.hobby}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js-

```
var app = angular.module('angularTable', []);

app.controller('listdata', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.users = []; //declare an empty array

$http.get("mockJson/mock.json").success(function (response) {

    alert('');
    $scope.users = response; //ajax request to fetch data into $scope.data

    });

});
```

mock.json:-

```
[ { "id": 1, "first_name": "Jhon", "last_name": "show", "hobby": "Eating" },
{ "id": 2, "first_name": "Jhon2", "last_name": "show2", "hobby": "Eating2" },
{ "id": 3, "first_name": "Jhon3", "last_name": "show3", "hobby": "Eating3" },
{ "id": 4, "first_name": "Jhon4", "last_name": "show4", "hobby": "Eating4" },
{ "id": 5, "first_name": "Jhon5", "last_name": "show5", "hobby": "Eatin5" },
{ "id": 6, "first_name": "Jhon6", "last_name": "show6", "hobby": "Eating6" },
{ "id": 7, "first_name": "Jhon7", "last_name": "show7", "hobby": "Eating7" },
{ "id": 8, "first_name": "Jhon8", "last_name": "show8", "hobby": "Eating8" },
{ "id": 9, "first_name": "Jhon9", "last_name": "show9", "hobby": "Eating9" },
{ "id": 10, "first_name": "Jhon10", "last_name": "show10", "hobby": "Eating10" },
{ "id": 11, "first_name": "Jhon11", "last_name": "show11", "hobby": "Eating11" },
{ "id": 12, "first_name": "Jhon12", "last_name": "show12", "hobby": "Eating12" },
{ "id": 13, "first_name": "Jhon13", "last_name": "show13", "hobby": "Eating13" },
{ "id": 14, "first_name": "Jhon14", "last_name": "show14", "hobby": "Eating14" },
{ "id": 15, "first_name": "Jhon15", "last_name": "show15", "hobby": "Eating15" },
{ "id": 16, "first_name": "Jhon16", "last_name": "show16", "hobby": "Eating16" },
{ "id": 17, "first_name": "Jhon17", "last_name": "show17", "hobby": "Eating17" },
{ "id": 18, "first_name": "Jhon18", "last_name": "show18", "hobby": "Eating18" },
{ "id": 19, "first_name": "Jhon19", "last_name": "show19", "hobby": "Eating19" },
{ "id": 20, "first_name": "Jhon20", "last_name": "show20", "hobby": "Eating20" },
{ "id": 21, "first_name": "Jhon21", "last_name": "show21", "hobby": "Eating21" },
{ "id": 22, "first_name": "Jhon22", "last_name": "show22", "hobby": "Eating22" },
{ "id": 23, "first_name": "Jhon23", "last_name": "show23", "hobby": "Eating23" },
{ "id": 24, "first_name": "Jhon24", "last_name": "show24", "hobby": "Eating24" },
{ "id": 25, "first_name": "Jhon25", "last_name": "show25", "hobby": "Eating25" }]
```

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: No errrors in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any issues with your code but made a slight modify of defining ng-app on body instead of html tag.

Here is the working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5XhnYhxrCQ28yAA8MiVL?p=preview) for the same

```
<body>
<div role="main" class="container theme-showcase" ng-app="angularTable">
    <div class="" style="margin-top:90px">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h2 id="tables">Searching,Sorting and Pagination in angularJS.</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="bs-component" ng-controller="listdata">
                <table class="table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Hobby</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
                            <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{user.hobby}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Modify your HTML `<head>` tags like below

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="angularTable">
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>
</head>
```

From comments by OP the issue is with `$http.get` method which is using `.success` function which is no more used in 1.6 version.

Either OP can fallback to <1.6 versions or use `.then` function for success callbacks

Here is the updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MfXVXnJ6Qfftahis49Pd?p=preview)

When using `.then` function it has all the objects related to a response hence for data retrieval we should use `response.data`

Comment: Try moving your script tags to head tags instead loading them in the body as Angular needs to be compiled first to render the data in scope

Comment: can you try to create a fiddle or plunker out of your code ? As I used your same code and it worked perfectly for me, the only difference was the script tags

Comment: Here is the update plunker of yours with bootstrap modules added and now the table looks more cool. https://plnkr.co/edit/IYAeOQVb9hxV7xlZyDCK?p=preview

Comment: please check the plunker now.

Comment: Please checck my updated answer it's the issue with angular version you are using! 1.6 doesn't support .success function for $http. You can lower your angular version if that's not a concern or else you can use .then function instead

Comment: I have added then instead of success in js, still I am getting blank page..it is frustrating..

Comment: Please check the updated plunker in the answer you need to use $scope.users = response.data; for retrieving data

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the angular version.
$http.get(...).success is removed in angular 1.6

Try using the below, it uses the new syntax

```
var app = angular.module('angularTable',[]);

app.controller('listdata',function($scope,$http){

   $scope.users = [];

   $http.get("demo.json").then(function(response){
    $scope.users = response.data;
   });

});
```